# Demo project for SDL Web 8.5 Core Service

Tags: core-service, web8.5, java

I need a full Java project setup for Core Services to get Component details by using Java program

Comment: Do you. Perhaps you have a question too? Are you asking if there's a default one with the installation, if there's something someone can magic-up or what it is you need to do to enact this?

Did you already search for this? did you see something similar that didn't quite fit?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange! @Mark points out some StackExchange basics for sure, specifically on asking a question that can be, well, answered. See the help section for [how to ask questions on topic](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as well as [what kinds of questions to ask or not ask](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). As you explore the Content Manager APIs, I encourage you to ask more specific, "answerable" questions, starting with what you've tried, researched, or encountered in terms of issues.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TridionStackexchange!

Take look at the documentation for [Interacting with the Core Service from Java](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-B2C3F336-0051-4576-8FFB-06A068CAA31F)

For a starting point, Mihas has done a Core service with Java client and placed his proxy classes in a [Google code](https://code.google.com/p/yet-another-tridion-blog/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Core%20Service%20Java%20Client) (open source) project, and he has written a few blogs about them:

- http://yatb.mitza.net/2013/04/streamlining-core-service-java-client.html
- http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/a-core-service-java-client.html
- http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/java-core-service-trouble-with-datetime.html
- http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/core-service-java

Check those out and you will have everything you need to get started. Keep in mind these examples are written against SDL Tridion 2013, to have them work against version SDL Web 8.5, you will need to regenerate the proxies as the endpoints are different.

I hope it helps